# Simulating a queue in R

Tags: probability, distributions, queueing, operations-research

It's noted that the number of folks in a stationary system will maintain an average equal to the rate of arrival multiplied by the mean of the service distribution.

Where the formula $L = \lambda$ is valid for any queuing model in steady state. $L$ and $w$ are longterm steadystate average values, respectively. \lambda denotes the arrival rate to the system.

Where we can add up the total time in the system as:

$\sum w_{j} = \sum i T_i$

And let $T_i$ represent the time units in which $i$ entities were in the system.

But things are always more interesting with sample sizing and simulating result, so say in 5000 iterations we estimate a state of a system in 1-min intervals, between the first minute and the last arrival at a determined time.

So if use a random interarrival rate of $\lambda = 2$ per minute and the service distribution is $N(8,1)$ minutes for the system.

How can I model this is R, using `rexp()` and `rnorm()`?

---

So far this is what I came up thus far

```
lambda <- 2
interarrivals <- rexp(5000,lambda)  ## (2 items per minute)
```

Provided the $\mu$ we expect that the interarrivals is about half a minute

```
mean(interarrivals) = .516
service.times <- rnorm(5000, mean=8,sd=1)
```

where the service distribution is $N(8,1)$

```
arrival.times <- cumsum(interarrivals)
departure.times <- arrival.times+service.times
```

Where I am having is determining at time 1-min to the last, how many individuals remain in the system...

Having issues conceptualizing the model ~ this is what you are supposed to estimate (Little's law), which states that rate of arrival = 2 units per minute * mean of the service distribution = 8.

Also, I don't know how to convert to `ts()` for plotting.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Questions about coding are off topic here. But it seems like there is a statistical issue here, too. If you remove the bits about coding, I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I will illustrate how this 'discretization' of a continuous-time Markov process
can be done, using a process that is a little simpler than your queue.

**Continuous-time Markov process.** Consider a continuous time Markov process roughly modeling decay of performance of a machine and rate of its repair. States are $S = \{1,2,3\},$ where 1 = poor, 2 = fair, 3 = good performance. Instantaneous transition intensities are as follows:

- If in state 1, the machine is repaired at rate $\lambda = 3,$ moving to state 3.
- If in state 2, it decays to state 1 at rate $\mu = 2.$
- If in state 3, it decays at rate $2\mu$, moving to state 1 or 2 with equal probabilities.

The $Q$-matrix can be expressed in R as

```
Q = matrix(c(-3,  0,  3,
              2, -2,  0,
              2,  2, -4), byrow=T, nrow=3)
```

One can solve balance equations to show that the long run probabilities in being
in the states are given by $P = (.4, .3, .3).$

**Similar discrete Markov Chain.** Now we 'discretize' the chain by viewing it at one minute intervals (elapsed time $s).$. The rate of *not* moving out of state 1 is
$$e^{-\lambda s} = e^{-1/20} \approx 19/20 = 57/60.$$
Similarly, the probability of not moving from state 2 is $e^{-10} \approx 58/60,$ and the probability of nor moving from state 3 is about $56/60.$

Thus the transition matrix of the discrete-time chain can be written as

P = (1/60)*matrix(c(57,  0,  3,
                        2, 58,  0,
                        2,  2, 56), byrow=T, nrow=3)

It is easy to show that the steady state distribution of this Markov Chain is
$(.4, .3, .3).$

Consider transitions from state 1 to state 3 ("repairs"): The original continuous-time process makes such transitions according to an exponential distribution at the rate $\lambda = 3$ per hour---on average 20 minutes apart.

In contrast, the approximating discrete-time chain takes a geometrically distributed length of time to make this transition. It has probability $3/60 = 1/20$ of moving at each (one minute) step—on average one transition in 20 steps.

Observing only at one minute intervals, we would seldom see a difference between the two models. One relatively rare exception is that the continuous-time process could conceivably move from state 1 to state 3 to state 2 within one minute, whereas the discrete-time chain cannot move from state 1 to state 2 in a one-minute step.

**Simulating the chain.** The discrete-time chain can be simulated using the program below. We use an unusually large number of iterations here because the P-matrix specifies a chain that rarely moves. The result is consistent with the stationary distribution above.

```
P = matrix((1/60)*c(57,  0,  3,
                     2, 58,  0,
                     2,  2, 56), byrow=T, nrow=3)

set.seed(2014)
m = 10^6;  y = numeric(m);  y[1] = 2
for (i in 2:m) y[i] = sample(1:3, 1, prob=P[y[i-1],])
round(summary(as.factor(y))/m, 4)

     1      2      3
0.4023 0.2970 0.3006
```

**Addendum. Simulating the process in continuous time.**
Somewhat more intricately, the original continuous-time process can also be simulated in R. (Particularly, for complex queues, many authors prefer the simplicity of simulation the discrete-time analogue.)

```
set.seed(1492)
lam = 3;  mu = 2           # repair and decay rates
kap = c(lam, mu, 2*mu)     # rates for leaving states (1, 2, 3)
m = 50000;  x = t = numeric(m)
x[1] = 2                   # start in state 2
for (i in 2:m)
  {
  t[i-1] = rexp(1, kap[x[i-1]])
  if (x[i-1] == 1) x[i] = 3               # moving from 1 to 3
  if (x[i-1] == 2) x[i] = 1               # moving from 2 to 1
  if (x[i-1] == 3) x[i] = sample(1:2, 1)  # moving from 3 to 1 or 2
  }                                       #  with prob 1/2 each

plot(c(0,cumsum(t)[1:50]), c(x[1],x[1:50]), type="S",
  ylab = "State", xlab="Elapsed time", main="")
d = 2*(lam + mu);  p = c(2*mu, lam, lam)/d  # exact p
t.avg = numeric(3)                          # simulated p
for (j in 1:3) {t.avg[j] = sum(t[x==j])/sum(t)}
round(cbind(states=1:3, p, t.avg), 3)

##   states    p  t.avg
##        1  0.4  0.400
##        2  0.3  0.301
##        3  0.3  0.299
```

[image]